# En un reporte de Telerik se puede poner un gráfico de barras?

Tags: report, telerik

Puse un gráfico de barras abajo de un reporte y en el preview no se ve nada.

Otra cosa, como puedo encadenar el filtro que tiene el reporte con el gráfico?

[image: Imagen del reporte]

Comment: Hola Jhon, deberías editar la pregunta para añadir algo más de información: ¿cómo estás generando el reporte? ¿qué filtros quieres encadenar? Con la información provista es difícil saber cómo ayudarte o con qué necesitas ayuda. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información. Y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general (y con ello ganarás una nueva medalla).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Visual Studio fue muy difícil y no pude... pero con el Report Designer de Telerkik, sí.

El asunto era que al usar RTrim y LTrim en el query que lleva los datos al reporte, la fecha cambiaba de formato, por eso missmatch con el filtro. Y lo bueno de esta herramienta es que permite agregar el gráfico, algo que quería hacer en VS pero que no mostraba nada en el preview, además el gráfico queda enlazado con los filtros.